# How to filter for a specific number of rows in Jupyter Notebook with Python 3?

Tags: python

[image: Data Frame]

I figured out how to sort the data from most recent to least recent, but I'm having trouble figuring out a command to show a specific time frame. The years I'm looking for are 2016-2008. I included the data frame that needs to be filtered in the link.

It's my first time posting a picture, so it's only allowing me to post as it link. I hope it's visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it this is a pandas dataframe?

it should just be:

```
rows = data[(data.years >= 2008) & (data.years <= 2016)]
```

where the dataframe is called 'data' and years is the row.

Comment: I had to cap the Y and remove the S in Years but it worked after that. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the column's name is not exactly "years"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
rows = all_rows[(all_rows['Year']>=2008) and (all_rows['Year']<=2016)]
```

Comment: My file name is "data" by the way. I tried this   data.all_rows['Year']>=2008 && all_rows['Year']<=2016  and it had this error File "<ipython-input-18-3c539b52823d>", line 1
    data.all_rows['Year']>=2008 && all_rows['Year']<=2016
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Then I tried this  rows= data.all_rows['Year']>=2008 && all_rows['Year']<=2016 and it had similar error   File "<ipython-input-19-5194e79b0bdd>", line 1
    rows= all_rows['Year']>=2008 && all_rows['Year']<=2016
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax